# How to find the dot product inside of a square

Tags: vectors

Let ABCD be a square, K the midpoint of AB, M a point on the diagonal AC such that $AM:MC=3:1$.  Use the dot-product to show that angle $KMD=90$

I know that two vectors are orthogonal if their dot-product equals zero.  I have tried locating one of the vertices at the origin, making the sides length of 1, and computing sides but I got stuck after finding the lengths.  Next I tried using the fact that a square is 4 right angles and started naming sides as vectors and trying to move them along the lines but I could not find vector DM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overrightarrow{AK}=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{AB}$.

$\overrightarrow{AM}=\frac{3}{4}\overrightarrow{AC}=\frac{3}{4}(\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AD})$

$\overrightarrow{MD}=\overrightarrow{AD}-\overrightarrow{AM}=-\frac{3}{4}\overrightarrow{AB}+\frac{1}{4}\overrightarrow{AD}$

$\overrightarrow{KM}=\overrightarrow{AM}-\overrightarrow{AK}=\frac{1}{4}\overrightarrow{AB}+\frac{3}{4}\overrightarrow{AD}$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{KM}\cdot\overrightarrow{MD}&=-\frac{3}{16}\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}-\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AD}+\frac{3}{16}\overrightarrow{AD}\cdot\overrightarrow{AD}\\
&=-\frac{3}{16}|\overrightarrow{AB}|^2+\frac{3}{16}|\overrightarrow{AD}|^2\\
&=0
\end{align}

$\angle KMD=90^\circ$.

[image]